# Differential integral solution of convolution-like equation

Tags: convolution

I try to find a closed form for the variable $x$ in the equality $x(t, \tau) = \int\limits_{\tau}^t \, f(t, s) x(s) ds$, without success. If you want a less general example, consider the linear multivariable example $\dot{x} = Ax + Bu$, whose solution for any $u$ is $x(t) = e^{A(t-\tau)} x_\tau + \int_{\tau}^{t} e^{A(t-s)} B u(s) ds$ and for u equal to $K x(\cdot)$ is $x(t, \tau) = e^{(A+BK)(t-\tau)} x_\tau$. The main motivation for such statement is the closed solution for differential equation $\dot{x}(t) = (\alpha(t) \, A + \beta(t) \, B) \, x(t)$.

Comment: Please correct the formula for $x(t)$. It should not have the variable $\tau$ as integration variable and also as boundary of the integral.

Comment: I have done as requested.

Comment: Is $x$ a function of one or two variables? On the left hand side of $x(t, \tau) = \int\limits_{\tau}^t \, f(t, s) x(s) ds$ it takes two variables, but inside the integral it only takes one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary (because slightly confusing) to include the start time $\tau$ into the solution $x(t)$ of
$\dot x=Ax+Bu\,,\,\,x(\tau)=x_\tau\,.$ It is trivial that this linear inhomogenous ODE is equivalent to
$$
x(t)=e^{A(t-\tau)}x_\tau+\int_\tau^te^{A(t-s)}\,B\,u(s)\,ds\quad\quad (1)
$$ and that for $u(s)=Kx(s)$ we have a homogenous ODE $\dot x=(A+BK)x\,,$ with solution $x(t)=e^{(A+BK)(t-\tau)}x_\tau\,.$

It looks like you want to generalize (1) to
$$
x(t)=x_0+\int_0^tf(t,s)\,x(s)\,ds\quad\quad (2)
$$
(I assume $\tau=0$ for simplicity). The integral equation (2) is equivalent to the integro differential equation
\begin{align}
\dot x(t)&=f(t,t)\,x(t)+\int_0^t\partial_tf(t,s)\,x(s)\,ds\,\\
&=\int_0^t\Big\{f(t,t)\,f(t,s)+\partial_tf(t,s)\Big\}\,x(s)\,ds\,.
\end{align}
This looks more complicated than (2).
However, when $\partial_tf(t,s)=A(t)f(t,s)$ we have again a homogeneous ODE
$$
\dot x(t)=f(t,t)\,x(t)+A(t)\,x(t)
$$
with solution
$$
x(t)=x_0\exp\Big(\int_0^tf(s,s)+A(s)\,ds\Big)\,.
$$
For general $f$ I cannot think of a closed form solution. Also if -as you assumed- $x_0=0$ in (2) then the only solution is the trivial one $x\equiv0\,.$

Comment: The motivation for stated problem corresponds to closed solution of $\dot{x} = (\alpha(t) A + \beta(t) B) \, x$

Comment: which in turn corresponds to $x(t)=x(0)+\int_0^t f(s)\,x(s)\,ds\,.$ The fact that you write $f(t)=\alpha(t)A+\beta(t)B$ adds nothing to the problem. If you allow $f$ to depend on $t$ and $s$ see (2) and what follows.

Comment: I allow it, but he is stubborn. Can you see a manner to convert it into the suggested form?

Comment: Do you mean $f(t, s) = \alpha(t) A + \beta(s) B$, for example?

Comment: No. This does obviously not satisfy $\partial_tf(t,s)=A(t)\,f(t,s)\,.$

Comment: Do you have any idea how to obtain $f(t, s)$ based on the original matrix $\alpha A + \beta B$?

Comment: First of all, it is still not clear to me what you are actually trying to achieve. It could help if you edit your question to give more background. If you want $f(t,s)$ having the form $\alpha\,A+\beta\,B$ **and** satisfy $\partial_tf(t,s)=C(t)f(t,s)$ (some other $C(t)$) to obtain a tractable solution $x(t)$ you *could obviously* assume $\alpha(t,s)A(t,s)+\beta(t,s)B(t,s)\,.$ **However**: this is in no way more general than working just with $f(t,s)\,.$ It adds nothing new to the problem.

Comment: I added a last sentence on the statement to clarify the original motivation for general form.